# Is it possible in IIS 8 to rewrite a folder to a subdomain on a different server?

Tags: asp.net, url, iis, azure, url-rewriting

I am migrating an ASP.NET web site to Azure. Currently we have MovableType installed on the server that hosts our web site, and a /blog/ application in IIS that points to the files published by MovableType. In moving to Azure I would prefer to install MovableType on a server separate from our web site, but that means that our blog content will no longer reside on the same server as the main site.

If I setup a subdomain to point to the blog server is there a way to rewrite, for example, www.mysite.com/blog/post.html to blog.mysite.com/blog/post.html?

I have tried the URL rewrite module, but it seems that it wants the rewritten Url to be on the same server.  I have also tried HTTP redirects, but that changes the Url in the address bar.

If this isn't possible with rewrites or redirection, what would be the best approach?  Is mapping a drive from one Azure server to another a reliable option?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get this working using the URL Rewrite extension in IIS.  The solution was to use the "Reverse Proxy" template.  This template requires the installation of the Application Request Routing extension, but worked perfectly.

In case anyone else is trying to do this, here are my values for the key settings.

```
Match URL pattern: ^blog/(.*)
Rewrite URL: http://blog.mysite.com/blog/{R:1}
```